# Use NPM as a build tool with a flat hierarchy?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, bower

After days of trying to piece together a dev environment with Node.js, NPM, Bower and Gulp (not to mention actual libs), I came across these two articles about how one can just use NPM as a build tool:

- http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/why-we-should-stop-using-grunt/
- http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

The essence of the article; to use as `npm lint`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "latest",
},
"scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint **.js"
}
```

To get an efficient client side bundle I've used Gulp, because of the flat dependency hierarchy that it provides. But simplifying the dev environment down to just Node/NPM is tempting. Is there a way to get the flat dependency hierarchy with just NPM?

Comment: Newer versions of NPM (3.x) gives a more flat dependency hierarchy, as flat as it can be without having version conflicts.

Comment: What i'm curious of is why it being flat matters in your case. Generally when using NPM to pull in client-side modules, you use something like gulp/grunt to copy the files you need from node_modules to your public folder. Without that step you would have to send the node_modules folder along (or at least rename it), meaning you'll have many extra files in your production build. You don't need the source files, only the compiled one for client-side work.

Comment: Of course, you very well could manage that part with npm too, though to me it would seem a bit more difficult to maintain if you had a lot of things you needed to move around/minify/concat etc.

Comment: The point here was to avoid Grunt/Gulp if NPM really can do most of that work. I hadn't thought of copying the needed libs to a public folder before building. Not quite what I hoped for, but definitely feasible.

Comment: It's an issue of scale. If your project simply needs one module to be moved, it's very easy. but if you need 15, it's going to get messy.

Comment: True. The app will have some fairly heavy duty parts, so what I'm trying to achieve is both eliminate duplicate dependencies and still keep low overhead in the dev environment.